# Find the value of constant $A$ such that the function is continuous in the entire line

Tags: calculus, limits

$f(x)= -4 \cdot \dfrac {\sin x}{x}$, $x<0$

$f(x) = a+7x$, x>0$

I have tried equating both as equal when $x=0$
but that leads to:

$-4\cdot\dfrac{\sin 0}{0}=a+7(0)$

which shows $a=0$

I have been provided answer key but this answer does not matches it what am I missing here ?

Comment: In this, you seem to be saying that $$-4\times\frac{\sin 0}{0}=0$$ But when you have division by $0$, you should be very careful, and use the fact that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\ne0$$ do you know what this limit is?

Answer (score 1):

The first function isn't defined at $0$, because of division by zero, but if you want to assign to $f(0)$ the value of the limit as you approach $0$, you get that:

$$f(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}  -4 \cdot \frac{\sin x}{x} = -4$$

using the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

Then you will get that $a=-4$

Comment: OH you are right (sin(0)/0)=1 i had forgotten that identity thanks for reminding me

Comment: @FayzanQureshi You have to be more careful. $\frac{\sin 0}{0}$ isn't defined. In fact $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$